# R function to use passed object name+ another name inside

Tags: r

I want to build a function that calls another object that name is related to the main object name.

For example, Main object is 'VCU_Players' and the other object is 'VCU_Players_opp'

in my function i need to use both objects in my calculations.

So i am trying to do

```
my_function<- function(x) {
  y<-deparse(substitute(x))
  z<-"_opp"
  y<- paste(y,z,sep = "")

#My Calculations
x$newfield<- x$pts+ y$pts
Return(x)
}
```

Now i want to pass the object VCU_Players to the function

my_function(VCU_Players)

But the function doesn't figure the VCU_Players_opp  object

Comment: This makes me wonder if you have many if not hundreds of such pairings flooding your global environment. If so, consider incorporating them all in a large list with named elements that you can reference with string literals. Advise on your larger setup.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but can you give me an example please ?

Comment: Can you give me your setup? Again, do you have many such pairings of *_players* and *_opp* objects beyond VCU? How were they produced? From loop? From file? Once I know that I can help.

Comment: Right now i Have 12 teams where each have an object of TEAMNAME_Players and TEAMNAME_opp  , They are produced from an excel file .  I am trying to add some calculations on the TEAMNAME_Player object but some of these calculations need the _opp  so thats why i am looking for this

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing string literals and using `get()` to retrieve corresponding object:

```
teams <- c("Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5", "Team6",
           "Team7", "Team8", "Team9", "Team10", "Team11", "Team12")

my_function <- function(i) {
  x <- get(paste0(i, "_players"))
  y <- get(paste0(i, "_opp"))

  # My Calculations
  x$newfield <- x$pts + y$pts    
  return(x)
}

dfList <- lapply(teams, my_function)
```

Ideally, however is working with a few lists of many objects, and not separate multiple objects in your global environment. Try importing from your data source (i.e., Excel) multiple objects into single lists:

```
teamdfs <- c(Team1_players, Team2_players, Team3_players, Team4_players, Team5_players, Team6_players,
             Team7_players, Team8_players, Team9_players, Team10_players, Team11_players, Team12_players)

team_oppdfs <- c(Team1_opp, Team2_opp, Team3_opp, Team4_opp, Team5_opp, Team6_opp,
                 Team7_opp, Team8_opp, Team9_opp, Team10_opp, Team11_opp, Team12_opp)

my_function <- function(x, y) {
  # My Calculations
  x$newfield <- x$pts + y$pts
  return(x)
}

dfList <- mapply(my_function, teamdfs, team_oppdfs, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
          # EQUIVALENT TO Map(my_function, teamdfs, team_oppdfs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, When i tried this (get(paste0(i, "_opp")))  outside a function it worked.  But when i include it in the function it gives an error  : Error in get(paste0("x", "_opp")) : object 'x_opp' not found.  When i try x without the " "  it gives an error of : Error in get(paste0(x, "_opp")) : 
  object 'c(1, 12, 4, 10, 2, 20, 5, 0, 23, 13, 15, 14)_opp' not found

Comment: I checked my mock data with this routine without issue with `get()`. Can you carefully check names? You change `i` and `x` here. Do note: R is case sensitive. Align to your actual object names which may differ here.

Comment: No luck? Why did you use `x` and even more why did you quote it? My solution uses numbered teams. Be sure to change to actual team names like *VCU*. Also, it seems you are passing actual object into function. For first `lapply` solution, pass list of team name strings. For `mapply`, pass actual objects (list of dfs).